# How to solve this second order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is given by:

$$ \frac{dv}{du} (2 u\frac{1-uv}{1+uv} + u) = \frac{v}{2} \frac{d^2v}{du^2} + v\frac{1-uv}{1+uv} $$

I tried using Mathematica for this differential equation, it's not giving me an answer.

Comment: Why do you expect a symbolically expressible solution? Did you try to replace $v=uy$?